# How can i make my 1,1,3 dimensioned array a 1,3 in python?

Tags: python, numpy

Im pretty new to array and coding.I have a problem were my arrays end up looking like this:
`a = [[[1, 2, 3]]]`

how can I make it look like this?:
`a = [[1, 2, 3]]`

this is a problem because in its state right now i cant pass it through the dot function it returns this value eror.

ValueError: shapes `(1,1,3)` and `(1,1,3)` not aligned: `3 (dim 2) != 1 (dim 1)`

Comment: That's still not going to work even once you have a `(1, 3)` shape. It sounds like you've got deeper problems with your shape management.

Comment: try this: a=a[0]

Comment: What `dot` do you want to do?  What's the dimension that you are summing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just grab the first element of the double-nested array?

```
a = [[[1, 2, 3]]]
b = a[0]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with multiple nested lists like this,

```
a = [[[1,2,3]],[[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9]]]
```

you can remove one dimension like this:

```
b = [entry[0] for entry in a]

print(b)

>>> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For `numpy` arrays, you can use [`np.squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)

e.g.

```
>>> a = np.array([[[1, 2, 3]]])
>>> a.shape
(1, 1, 3)
>>> np.squeeze(a, axis=0).shape
(1, 3)
```